# Syncfusion Gantt - Angular library. Create custom tooltip for event markers

Tags: angular, typescript, syncfusion, ej2-syncfusion, ej2-gantt

I'm trying to understand how we can customize the tooltip of the event markers in the syncfusion gantt library made for angular.

There are examples of creating custom tooltips for the gantt chart; but they seem to only be for the task and the baseline items. I can't find an example of how to create a custom tooltip for the event markers.

By default the tooltip looks like this

[image: standard event marker tooltip]

What I'm trying to achieve mostly is the format of the date. Our date for the system needs to be formatted as `YYYY-MM-DD`, but I can't understand how to create a custom tooltop.

On the official documentation example page they have this:
https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/demos/#/material/gantt/tooltip-template

Which shows you how to get a custom baseline tooltip.

[image: example of custom baseline tooltip]

But how can you get a custom tooltip for the event markers?

---

### Update:

The accepted answer by @MonishaS was perfect. I did not know you could do that. I don't know if there's a link to it in the documentation but it works perfectly.

For my use case though, the stackblitz example posted removes all other tooltips. There's a small modification in the stackblitz that you can see here on my fork of the accept answer's stackblitz:
https://angular-4lnh62-entx4h.stackblitz.io

The change is basically as follows:

```
if (args.args.target.className === 'e-event-markers') {
      args.cancel = true;
    }
```

Comment: I did a little investigation on this topic, and it seems like with the current version out as of 01 Aug 2022, this isn't possible. There's an event that's list here in the docs - https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/demos/#/material/gantt/events that mentions `beforeTooltipRender`. While debugging, I found that the task and baseline have a data attribute that is populated. The data is not populated for the event marker. I think syncfusion will need to update the library for this to be possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can customize the tooltips for the event markers by creating custom tooltips using the ejs-tooltip control. Using this control, you can customize the dates to the format you want and set it as the content of the tooltip in the [beforeRender](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/documentation/api/tooltip/#beforerender) event. The below code snippets demonstrate the solution.

**App.component.html**

```
<ejs-tooltip id="tooltip" target='.e-span-label' (beforeRender)="onBeforeRender($event)" [content]="content">
```

**App.component.ts**

```
public onBeforeRender(args: any) {
  let label =
    '<tr class = "e-gantt-tooltip-rowcell"><td>Label:</td><td colspan="3">' +
    args.target.innerHTML +
    '</td></tr>';
  let date =
    '<tr class = "e-gantt-tooltip-rowcell"><td>Date:</td><td colspan="3">' +
    this.formatDate(args.target.offsetParent.ariaLabel.split(' ')[2]) +
    '</td></tr>';
  this.content =
    '<table class = "e-gantt-tooltiptable"><tbody>' +
    label +
    date +
    '</tbody></table>';
}



public formatDate(date) {
  var d = new Date(date),
      month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
      day = '' + d.getDate(),
      year = d.getFullYear();

  if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
  if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;
  return [year, month, day].join('-');
}
```

**Sample:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4lnh62?file=app.component.ts

Comment: Monisha, thank you so much! This is a life saver! It works just as expected :)

One thing that I have just changed with this implementation is that I still want the tooltips to show for the others. So instead of always canceling the event on the zbeforeTooltipRender` I've made this adjustment: `if ($event.args.target.className === 'e-event-markers') {` then it will only cancel for the event markers. Here is my update version: https://angular-4lnh62-entx4h.stackblitz.io